# pyspark: filter values in one dataframe based on array values in another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pypsark dataframe like this:

```
|                name|segment_list|rung_list  |
+--------------------+------------+-----------+
|   Campaign 1       | [1.0,  5.0]|  [L2,  L3]|
|   Campaign 1       |       [1.1]|       [L1]|
|   Campaign 2       |       [1.2]|       [L2]|
|   Campaign 2       |       [1.1]|  [L4,  L5]|
+--------------------+------------+-----------+
```

I have another pyspark dataframe that has segment and rung for every customer:

```
+-----------+---------------+---------+
|customer_id|     segment   |rung     |
+-----------+---------------+---------+
|  124001823|            1.0|       L2|
|  166001989|            5.0|       L2|
|  768002266|            1.1|       L1|
+-----------+---------------+---------+
```

What I want is a final output that figures out the customers based on the segment and rung list. The final output should be something like the following:

```
|                name|customer_id |   
+--------------------+------------+
|   Campaign 1       | 124001823  | 
|   Campaign 1       | 166001989  | 
|   Campaign 1       | 768002266  | 
+--------------------+------------+
```

I tried using udf but that approach didnt quite work. I would like to avoid using a for loop on a collect operation or going row by row. So I am primarily looking for a groupby operation on name column.

So I want a better way to do the following:

```
for row in x.collect():
    y = eligible.filter(eligible.segment.isin(row['segment_list'])).filter(eligible.rung.isin(row['rung_list']))
```

Comment: what is the condition of the mapping? for campaign 1, should `1.0` be checked with `L2` and `5.0` be checked with `L3`  and `1.1` be checked with `L1`, or can it be any segment within the list and any rung within the list? for the latter, `124001823` will be mapped with both campaigns

Comment: hi @samkart Thanks for asking. The condition is as described in the for loop. So you are essentially going by each row and filtering the segment and rung for that row. Each row is independent of the other so you will have duplicates and thats fine.

Comment: i don't understand how `124001823` was mapped to `Campaign 1`. based on your explanation, it shouldn't be mapped to either of the names.

Comment: My apologies. You are correct and I have changed the question accordingly! `124001823` is now segment `1.0` and rung `L2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try to use `array_contains` for the join conditions.

here's an example

```py
data1_sdf. \
    join(data2_sdf, 
         func.expr('array_contains(segment_list, segment)') & func.expr('array_contains(rung_list, rung)'), 
         'left'
         ). \
    select('name', 'customer_id'). \
    dropDuplicates(). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----------+-----------+
# |name      |customer_id|
# +----------+-----------+
# |Campaign 1|166001989  |
# |Campaign 1|124001823  |
# |Campaign 1|768002266  |
# |Campaign 2|null       |
# +----------+-----------
```

---

pasting the query plan spark produced

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Deduplicate [name#123, customer_id#129]
+- Project [name#123, customer_id#129]
   +- Join LeftOuter, (array_contains(segment_list#124, segment#130) AND array_contains(rung_list#125, rung#131))
      :- LogicalRDD [name#123, segment_list#124, rung_list#125], false
      +- LogicalRDD [customer_id#129, segment#130, rung#131], false

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
name: string, customer_id: string
Deduplicate [name#123, customer_id#129]
+- Project [name#123, customer_id#129]
   +- Join LeftOuter, (array_contains(segment_list#124, segment#130) AND array_contains(rung_list#125, rung#131))
      :- LogicalRDD [name#123, segment_list#124, rung_list#125], false
      +- LogicalRDD [customer_id#129, segment#130, rung#131], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [name#123, customer_id#129], [name#123, customer_id#129]
+- Project [name#123, customer_id#129]
   +- Join LeftOuter, (array_contains(segment_list#124, segment#130) AND array_contains(rung_list#125, rung#131))
      :- LogicalRDD [name#123, segment_list#124, rung_list#125], false
      +- Filter (isnotnull(segment#130) AND isnotnull(rung#131))
         +- LogicalRDD [customer_id#129, segment#130, rung#131], false

== Physical Plan ==
*(4) HashAggregate(keys=[name#123, customer_id#129], functions=[], output=[name#123, customer_id#129])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(name#123, customer_id#129, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#267]
   +- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[name#123, customer_id#129], functions=[], output=[name#123, customer_id#129])
      +- *(3) Project [name#123, customer_id#129]
         +- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, LeftOuter, (array_contains(segment_list#124, segment#130) AND array_contains(rung_list#125, rung#131))
            :- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[name#123,segment_list#124,rung_list#125]
            +- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode, [id=#261]
               +- *(2) Filter (isnotnull(segment#130) AND isnotnull(rung#131))
                  +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[customer_id#129,segment#130,rung#131]
```

seems it is not well optimized, I'm thinking there can be other optimized methods.